# Insert grid view data to already existing excel c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

My task is to add the Grid-view data to already formatted excel, I need to insert the  Grid-view data to first row of existing excel after the title/heading of the column. I don`t know where I am doing mistake while inserting data? please find my template excel, asp-dot-net code below.

**Excel**

```
Column1 Column2 Total1
                  =Sum(A2+B2)
                  =Sum(A2+B2)
```

Dotnet Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExcelExport._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
<p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Show" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" 
            onclick="Button2_Click" />
    </p>
<p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="A" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="B" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total1" HeaderText="FinalTotal" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Bind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExcelExport
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connection = null;
            connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Local"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string query = "select * from calc";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int gridi, j, value1, value2, value3;
            int rowcount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
            int Colcount = 3;
            String[] cellText;
            string constr, sheetinfo = "";

            string path = "D:\\Template.xlsx";
            constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            constr = string.Format(constr, path);
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                excel_con.Open();
                string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
                dtExcelData = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                String[] excelSheets = new String[dtExcelData.Rows.Count];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    i++;

                }
               // sheetinfo = excelSheets[2];


                try
                {


                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                    {

                        int count = 2;
                        value1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text.Trim());
                        value2 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text.Trim());
                        //value3 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text.Trim());
                        //string excelquery = "Insert into ["+sheetinfo+"A2:C20000] (Column1,Column2,Column3) values(" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")";
                        //string excelquery = "Insert into [sheet1$](A" + count + ",B" + count + ",C" + count + ") values(" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")";
                        string excelquery = "Insert into [Sheet1$](Column1, Column2) values(" + value1 + "," + value2 + ")";
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelquery, excel_con))
                        {
                            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                        }
                        excel_con.Close();
                        count += 1;

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```